# How to bind (like space) a key to the entire viewport?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, keyboard-shortcuts, angular-ui

I want to setup a key to respond anywhere I press in on my page, it's not bind to a single input for example.

I have tried to attach it to an element like a button or a div and it didn't worked at all.

```html
<div ui-keypress=" { 32: 'test()' } "></div>
<button ui-keypress=" { 32: 'test()' }">Test</button>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already found the answer, binding the event to the `<body>` allows a key to be tracked in the entire page.

In my case I wanted to capture the key press and handle it in a given controller, but the need to declare it on the body tag made me go a little bit forward. I have a main controller now that has an `emit` method, this way I can capture the event and route it to some kind of event bus.

On children scopes/controllers I can then capture the event and check to see if I have any listener to treat that keypress event. I have written an example on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jayrmotta/LfvkE/2/).

```javascript
"use strict";

angular.module('myApp', ['ui'])
    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.emit = function($event) {
            $scope.$broadcast('keypress', $event);
        };
    })
    .controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.$on('keypress', function($event, event) {
            keypressListeners.forEach(function(listener) {
                if (listener.keyCode === event.keyCode)
                    listener.fn();
            });
        });

        $scope.test = function() {
            alert('Works fine!');
        };

        var keypressListeners = [{ keyCode : 32, fn : $scope.test }];
});
```

```html
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl" ui-keypress=" { 32: 'emit($event)' } " >
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl"></div>
</body>
```

I'll appreciate comments and tips on this ;D